# What is the relationship between the three possible X coordinates corresponding to a Y coordinate?

Tags: secp256k1, math

Every possible X coordinate on secp256k1 has two corresponding Y coordinates, one of which is the negation of the other. I've also been told that every possible Y coordinate has three corresponding X coordinates ([due to the fact that the field size *p* = 1 mod 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673423/938129)). Is there also a nice relationship between them? Given a point on the curve, how can I obtain the other two points with the same Y coordinate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is!

For a given Y coordinate *y*, if on the curve, the three corresponding X coordinates are the cube roots of *y<sup>2</sup> - 7*. If you have any such cube root *y<sub>0</sub>*, then multiplying it with a cube root of *1* gives you another cube root - for the simple reason that *(y0 ∛1)<sup>3</sup> = y<sub>0</sub><sup>3</sup>(∛1)<sup>3</sup> = y<sub>0</sub><sup>3</sup>1 = y<sub>0</sub><sup>3</sup>*.

Modulo *p = 2<sup>256</sup>-2<sup>32</sup>-977* (the secp256k1 field size), the three cube roots of *1* are:

- *1* (obviously)
- *60197513588986302554485582024885075108884032450952339817679072026166228089408*
- *55594575648329892869085402983802832744385952214688224221778511981742606582254*

This is exactly analogous to what's going on for the corresponding Y coordinates given an X coordinate; only there the different Y coordinates are related by multiplication with *square* roots of *1*, namely *1* and *-1 = p-1*.